# Area 51's name is broken in app

Tags: bug, android-app, area-51

Small thing, but might be worth noting. I added Area 51 on my site list via the desktop site, but on my android app it shows up as
[image]
Tapping the broken name crashes the SE app. I get that Area 51 isn't supposed to be accessible by the app, but Area 51 Discussions (also on my site list in desktop) is simply removed from the app site list, so the same can probably be done for Area 51.